# How to create 3 legends for two traces of a grouped bar chart in Plotly JS?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
{
  sf_zoo : {
    giraffes: 10,
    lions: 5,
  },
    la_zoo : {
    giraffes: 5,
    lions: null,
    }
}
```

I want this data to produce a bar chart similar to this one, but with 3 legends instead of the 2:
[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/KKGNqVW?editors=1010
In the codepen example, I added a value of 2 to `la_zoo.lions` just so the bar can be displayed.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to display a third legend that should be gray and read "No data".

I want a bar chart that has two grouped bars, that can be colored red, blue or gray and 3 legends that correspond to those 3 colors: red, blue and gray.

I've tried using the `colorbar` prop of `data[type=bar].marker` but I can't separate the colorbar into 3 distinct colors: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/MWPbomO?editors=1010

I've also tried adding a dummy trace, but this only adds a third bar to each trace and hides it: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/yLRVXoP?editors=1010